# Timer management in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, wildfly

I have few automatic timers created using `@Schedule` annotation from 3 different `@Singleton` classes. They are running on wildfly server. How do I monitor the timers and make sure a timer has not stopped executing. These timers run hourly and I have to ensure they did not get terminated due to any issue.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like code below to your singletons and invoke `checkAlive()` method when you need to check if timers are alive:

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

private int initialNumberOfTimers;

@PostConstruct 
public void postCon() {
    initialNumberOfTimers = timerService.getTimers().size();
    System.out.println("Initial number of timers is: "+initialNumberOfTimers);
}

public void checkAlive() {
    Collection<Timer> timers = timerService.getTimers();

    if (timers.size() != initialNumberOfTimers) {
        System.out.println("ALARM!!! Number of timers is: " + timers.size());
    }

    for (Timer timer : timers) {
        System.out.println("Next timeout: " + timer.getNextTimeout().toString());
    }
}
```